# VBA Do Until Loop, shifting formula range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to run a loop through all the files in a folder, with these files I want to run a formula that will fill 20x2 cells (N1:O20 for example) and I want to retain the values found and append the next values to the bottom of the previous iteration.

Here is my the code I am working with, A1:K36004 is where the .dat files display their information.

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
'Adding clearcontents here clears formula value on next iteration

```
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
End With
'End Extraction
' Filter_Minute Macro
```

I need these values produced to be saved in location and next iteration moved down to next empty row

```
Range("N5").Select
Range("N5").Formula = "=INDEX($A$5:$A$36004,(ROW(N5)-5)*1200+1,1)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N5:N34"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("N5:N34").Select
    Range("N5:N34").Select
Range("O5").Select
Range("O5").Formula = "=MAX(INDEX($J$3:$J$36004,(ROW(H3)-3)*1200+1,1):INDEX($J$3:$J$36004,(ROW(H4)-3)*1200,1))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O5:O34"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("O5:O34").Select
    Range("O5:O34").Select

strFile = Dir
```

Loop

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo3Wa.png]

This picture shows what happens on the next iterations with the whole previous count being shifted.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely follow what you are asking (there's no question), but in the simple case of mechanically keeping track of a fixed destination range (N1:O20):

- x is first row in the range (1)
- number of rows (numRows) is a constant (20)
- a destination range in the VBA formulas is a string value (theRange) of the form "Nx:Ox+numRows-1"
- the first x value is assigned before loop starts
- for every iteration: theRange = "N" & str(x) & ":O" & str(x+numRows-1); {reference the range as `range.(theRange)` no quotes}; x = x + numRows; end-of-loop

The first time through: theRange="N1:O20". Second time: theRange="N21:O40"

Use meaningful variable names.

So basically, you keep track of the "endpoints of the frame" of information you are interested in, and then shift the frame. If your frame is of variable size, you will need a lot more logic to work out how to specify the endpoints. In your example text, the start row would be 1, in your picture, the start row would be 5.

Use a similar scheme for any other variable ranges you need in the same loop.

Comment: Ok thanks, there wasn't a question stated but you are onto what I was blabbing about. I'll try this out.